# Allow non-root users to mount kerberized CIFS share in their home only

Tags: linux, permissions, mount, cifs

#### **Actual situation**

I succeeded to make an heterogeneous share from a NetApp filer with NTFS security-style. I mount it on Linux ("winbinded" to Active Directory) with `mount.cifs` and options `user_xattr,cifsacl,multiuser,sec=krb5` (and others). The user has a valid Kerberos ticket at logon, and destroys it at logout. Permissions are managed on Windows only.

#### **Problem**

When permissions are modified, it does not apply, even by disconnecting and refreshing Kerberos ticket. To have it to apply, I need to unmount then remount the share. It is really not convenient since the share has to be accessed from different machines, and multiple users have access to it (and we cannot just wait for users to leave to apply some permissions).

#### **Possible workaround**

Each user should mount this share at logon, in a subdirectory of their home. This way, when permissions are modified for a specific user, only this user has to remount the share.

#### **Question**

**How can I allow users to mount this share in their own home directory?** `/etc/fstab` has to take a mountpoint as argument, and it is not reliable in my situation since multiple users will have to mount it in their respective homes.

**How can I allow users to mount a share anywhere in their home, but not anywhere else?** Something like `/home/%U/*` (still kerberized, so no credentials have to be passed).